# Two UIImage in one collectionview cell?

Tags: uiimage, uicollectionview

I want to put second UIImage inside collectionview cell but it return error

> "error: Illegal Configuration: The newIcon outlet from the DashboardViewController to the UIImageView is invalid. Outlets cannot be connected to repeating content.
>   "

Here is the picture to describe error that is generated :

[image: two uiimage inside one collectionview cell]

How to make two UIImage inside one collectionview cell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to add a new UIView into "dashboardCell". Once you've added a UIView you can then add more UIImages to that UIView.

[image: Multiple Images inside single UICollectionViewCell]